# Scroll to home page section with jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to scroll on homepage section with jquery. But I want to scroll on homepage no matter on which page I am.

The html is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a href="#home" class="nav-link p-0">Home </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#about-us" class="nav-link p-0">About us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#references" class="nav-link p-0">References</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the jquery function to animate scroll is as follows:

```
$(".nav-link").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 800, 'linear');
});
```

When I'm on homepage, thus on the url `www.my-url.com` and when I click on `.nav-link` it becomes `www.my-url.com/#about-us` and it scrolls where it needs to scroll with animation, and that is fine.

But the problem is when I'm on some other page than homepage, for example `www.my-url.com/some-page` and then when I click on  `.nav-link` it becomes `www.my-url.com/some-page#about-us` and it doesn't scroll.

How can I first go to homepage and then apply scroll animation if I click on the link from some other page than homepage?

Any idea?

Comment: The “problem” that it goes to `/some-page#about-us` when you are on `/some-page` already has in itself nothing to do with any added scrolling functionality, but with how relative URLs work. (_“when I click on .nav-link it becomes  www.my-url.com/#about-us”_ - not even that should happen with the code you have shown us, because you did prevent the default action of the link, and did not set the hash yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation?